# RocksDB data loss

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I have a stateful Kafka Streams application with logging disabled. The reason I had to disable it is because the aggregated state for some records can get very big, and sending an update to the changelog topic on every change is not feasible.

Therefore a StatefulSet is being used, where the rocksdb files are preserved upon restart. I was reading [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-tune-rocksdb-kafka-streams-state-stores-performance/) that Kafka Streams disable the rocksdb transaction log by default since it uses the changelog topic for fault tolerance, but in my case I guess it should be enabled. How can this be configured?

After reading this:

> Rocksdb is not highly available and does not have a failover scheme. That doesn’t mean you lose your state store data when you store it in RocksDB using Kafka Streams, because it’s Kafka Streams that makes RocksDB fault tolerant by replicating the state store data to a Kafka topic.

I got a little worried, since I am disabling the changelog topic. Are there any other precautions that need to be taken besides enabling transaction log, since I am relying solely on rocksdb files for fault tolerance?

Comment: In general, Kafka Streams does not send an update to the changelog for each change. Kafka Streams collects changes and sends them asynchronously to the changelog.

Comment: If the cache is disabled, Kafka Streams will send every update to the changelog. However, it will collect the changes into batches to reduce the overhead of sending them to Kafka. If the cache is enabled, Kafka Streams will not send every update to the changelog topic. A newer update written to the cache will overwrite an existing update stored in the cache. When the cache is flushed, the updates in the cache are send to the changelog. Also in this case the updates are collected and send asynchronously. In both cases, the updates are compacted in the changelog topic in Kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's disabled in Kafka Streams's default RocksDB [options](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/internals/RocksDBStore.java#L221) because the WAL is supposed to be Kafka itself:

```java
wOptions = new WriteOptions();
wOptions.setDisableWAL(true);
```

Not relying on changelog topics makes many things tricky as RocksDB is not meant to be a source of truth (Kafka is) but just as a helpful tool to do key-value store queries.

- You lose the re-hydration from the changelog topics to RocksDB when your app starts and has no RocksDB state yet. It's important to stay flexible with KStreams applications, like when you'll need to add/remove instances of your application — with changelog topics, it will rehydrate on a subset of the necessary data.
- Many KStreams operators write to changelog topics and your own topics using Kafka transactions. Writing to RocksDB is not transactional with Kafka: your app might write stuff to Kafka, then write to RocksDB. If your app stops before the RocksDB writes (restart, fail etc.), this will make your state inconsistent as KStreams has no clue it was not written to RocksDB (this is the first thing a KStream app checks when it starts, the consistency with the changelog topics and RocksDB, ensuring it's consistent)